# Apply Filter if given value is not null

Tags: java

I have a list of student objects. I want to filter this list based on some parameter using java 8. My code is like that

```
studentName = "test";

studentsList = students.stream().filter(s -> s.getName().equals(studentName )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I want to apply this filter if studentName is not null. If studentName  is null then I don't want this filter work. Can I make this studentName as optional in filter?

Comment: studentsList = students.stream().filter(s -> (!(s == null) && s.getName().equals(studentName ))).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 I think OP wants to skip the filter. Otherwise, the explicit check is unnecessary; `equals()` should  work fine.

Comment: Hi  @shomesl, yes I want to skip filter if the given value is null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either do it in two steps:

```
Stream<Student> studentStream = students.stream();
if (studentName != null) {
    studentStream = studentStream.filter(s -> s.getName().equals(studentName));
}
studentsList = studentStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or add the null check into the filter itself:

```
studentsList = students.stream()
        .filter(s -> studentName == null || s.getName().equals(studentName))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The first solution looks good however, there is a problem with it. IF I want to use filter for studentSurname, then filter doesnt behave like &&, the filter behave like ||

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Forexample,                                                                                           
 studentStream = studentStream.filter(s -> s.getName().equals(studentName));       
  studentStream = studentStream.filter(s -> s.getSurnameName().equals(studentSurName));      in this scenario, if I want to apply both codition together, the result won't return surname and name in the list as && condition. It will check if the list has name, then it will add to list. For surname it will look at it and if match it will add list

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Chained `filter()` calls act as an AND.

Comment: Forexample, let says student name is  = "testaname" and student surname = "testsurname", when I apply your solution, it won't bring the name and surname of a student. It will bring the name of = "testaname" of all students then it will bring all student surname with "testsurname" to the list

Comment: Yes, in your second solution it behave like chained, hovewer in the first one it doesnt. I try it however it doesnt bahave as chained

Comment: It's hard to follow without a full example. I suggest you post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar doubts about how to perform this operation.
Here is a clear answer with an example for it.
I have a class called Employee which has id, name and department in it.
And List of Employee  and I want to filter those where employee list is not null and
its department is 'management'
Something like this

```
Employee e1=new Employee();
    e1.setId("1");
    e1.setName("abc");
    e1.setDept("finance");
    Employee e2=new Employee();
    e2.setId("2");
    e2.setName("mno");
    e2.setDept(null);       
    Employee e3=new Employee();
    e3.setId("3");
    e3.setName("pqr");
    e3.setDept(null);
    Employee e4=new Employee();
    e4.setId("3");
    e4.setName("ghi");
    e4.setDept("management");
    
    List<Employee> list=new ArrayList();
    list.add(e1);
    list.add(e4);
    list.add(e3);
    list.add(e2);
    list=list.stream().filter(e->e.getDept()!=null && e.getDept().equals("management")).collect(Collectors.toList());// This will filter the list
```

Comment: The question asks how to skip filtering if 'studentName' is null.  It does not ask how to handle the case when 's.getName()' is null.