# Python function apply filter if value is not None on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello looking for python best practice advise here for a scenario

Want to put a function that takes multiple inputs from UI.
Param may have value or None.
Want to filter data frame by the values where available otherwise ignore that instead of filtering 4 times.

```
def my_function(name,age,lastName,city):

  if name is not None:
    df = df[(df["Name"]==name)]

  if age is not None:
    df = df[(df["Age"]>=age)]

  if lastName is not None:
    df = df[(df["LastName"]==lastName)]

  if city is not None:
    df = df[(df["City"]==city)]
```

Comment: Why negative vote? This is something you can do in C# or Java and I am just looking for best way to do it in Python? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55658366/apply-filter-if-given-value-is-not-null

Answer (score 0):

You can do `isin` but the input data type should be `list`

```
#name :['A','B'] 
#Age:[11,22] 
#lastName : ['C','D']
#city : ['E','F']
  filteredData = df[
  (df["Name"].isin(name)) 
& (df["Age"].isin(age))  
& (df["LastName"].isin(lastName))
& (df["City"].isin(city))
]

#(df["Age"].ge(age))
```

Comment: Interesting. But what if the filter needs to be changed slight say for age needs to be greater than instead of equals?

Comment: @Cannon Then the age input should be int